# Get data from Console of Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a command and use Eclipse to execute this command. The result print into Console tab.

```
String[] cmdLine = buildCommandLine(configuration, true);     
Process process = DebugPlugin.exec(cmdLine, null, null);     
DebugPlugin.newProcess(launch, process, "", null);
```

How can I get all data from Console tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an [org.eclipse.debug.core.IStreamListener](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fdebug%2Fcore%2FIStreamListener.html) to the process.

```
IProcess process = DebugPlugin.newProcess(launch, process, "", null);
IStreamsProxy streamsProxy = process.getStreamsProxy();
IStreamMonitor streamMonitor = streamsProxy.getOutputStreamMonitor();

IStreamListener yourListener = ....;

streamMonitor.addListener(yourListener );
```

I would do it this way, because your code above is "core code" (no ui code) `org.eclipse.debug.core`.
If you use the [MessageConsole](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2Fconsole%2FMessageConsole.html) as suggested in [How to read message from console tab view in eclipse plugin development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418118/how-to-read-message-from-console-tab-view-in-eclipse-plugin-development) you will introduce a dependency from core to ui code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My program need to run 2 commands. The second command will be run based on the result of previous command.

I used IStreamListener() to get result of first command and check condition to run second command but the output separate into 2 console output
How to append content of 2 commands into 1 console?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for the method `DebugPlugin.newProcess` says:

> Creates and returns a new process representing the given java.lang.Process. A streams proxy is created for the I/O streams in the system process.

So, there are two things notable here: First, this method returns something (that you are ignoring). Second, it has a *streams proxy* for accessing the I/O streams of the process. You simply must query them for the required output:

```
String[] cmdLine = buildCommandLine(configuration, true);
Process p = DebugPlugin.exec(cmdLine, null);
IProcess process = DebugPlugin.newProcess(launch, p, "");
process.getStreamsProxy().getErrorStreamMonitor().addListener(myErrorStreamListener());
process.getStreamsProxy().getOutputStreamMonitor().addListener(myOutputStreamListener());
```

You must implement the methods `myErrorStreamListener` and `myOutputStreamListener` to return appropriate listeners that are able to catch up the console output.

Comment: OK, I done it. Thanks